# Bash variable from command with pipes, quotes, etc

Tags: bash, variables, pipe

I have a command I'm using to get the hostname.localdomain:

```
dig axfr @dc1.localdomain.com localdomain.com | grep -i Lawler | awk '{ getline ; $1=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); print $1 ; exit }'
```

This nicely returns a result like:

> michael.lawler.localdomain.com

I'd like to further use that result as a variable in a Bash script.

It seems I'm having trouble getting past the first pipe.

If I `VAR="dig axfr @dc1.localdomain.com localdomain.com | grep -i Lawler | awk '{ getline ; $1=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); print $1 ; exit }'"`

...I get back the entire zone transfer. I've also tried many minor changes, adding `$` before the `dig` command, without quotes, but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: If your goal is to store the command to run it more than once, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"). If your goal is only to store the output, `var=$(command)`

Comment: FYI -- you can probably ask `dig` to give you less information, to make the output easier to parse. See for instance the `+short` option.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `awk '{ getline ; $1=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); print $1 ; exit }'` does what I need, `+short` actually doesn't work for my situation, not sure why..maybe because of OSX. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Both answers provided work as expected. Any thoughts on which is more susceptible to future complexity? I'd like to accept the one which provides the most forgiving flexibility. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a bash command stored as a string with quotes and asterisk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005192/how-to-execute-a-bash-command-stored-as-a-string-with-quotes-and-asterisk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
VAR=$( dig axfr @dc1.localdomain.com localdomain.com |
     grep -i Lawler |
     awk '{ getline ; $1=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); print $1 ; exit }' )
```

Comment: Using `$()` is generally preferred over backticks as backticks do not nest.  backticks are slightly more portable, but `$()` notation has been standard for about 20 years, and most shells accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Use backtics instead of quotes:

```
VAR=`dig axfr @dc1.localdomain.com localdomain.com | grep -i Lawler | awk '{ getline ; $1=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); print $1 ; exit }'`
```

Backtics actually mean "run whatever is in here and return standard out as the expression's value", but quotes don't do that.

Comment: Both do work well.  I think this way is just easiest to remember and works well on many systems.  As Pursell noted, it won't nest, but I don't think that's a problem in this case.  You can nest $() inside the backtics though, so it's not like a dead-end.  That said, I don't think there's really a clear winner.