# command does not execute as variable?

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick-convert

Whenever I try to execute the following shell command , it works properly .

```
convert maanavulu_GIST-TLOTKrishna.tif -alpha set -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -set option:distort:viewport 1000x1000 -distort perspective-projection '1.06,0.5,0,0,1.2,0,0,0' -trim 1.jpg
```

But , whenever I try assign the command to a variable and then execute it , it reports the following error .

```
convert.im6: invalid argument for option PerspectiveProjection : 'Needs 8 coefficient values' @ error/distort.c/GenerateCoefficients/873.
```

Comment: `whenever I try assign the command to a variable and then execute it` How are you doing it, can you show code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "assign the command to a variable and then execute it". There are various problems with things like `cmd="..."; $cmd`: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a bash command stored as a string with quotes and asterisk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005192/how-to-execute-a-bash-command-stored-as-a-string-with-quotes-and-asterisk)

Answer (score 3):

The short of it: it's best to:

- store your *arguments* in an *array*
- *not* including the command itself, for safety (preferable to an `eval` solution)
- then invoke the command with the array

```sh
# Store options in array - note that the filenames are excluded here, too,
# for modularity
opts=(-alpha set -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -set option:distort:viewport \
      1000x1000 -distort perspective-projection '1.06,0.5,0,0,1.2,0,0,0' -trim)

# Invoke command with filenames and saved options
convert maanavulu_GIST-TLOTKrishna.tif "${opts[@]}" 1.jpg
```

---

**Afterthought**: As @konsolebox and @chepner point out: using a *function* is probably the best choice (clear separation between fixed and variable parts, encapsulation, full range of shell commands available).

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to assign-and-execute a command is to use an array:

```
COMMAND=(convert maanavulu_GIST-TLOTKrishna.tif -alpha set -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -set option:distort:viewport 1000x1000 -distort perspective-projection '1.06,0.5,0,0,1.2,0,0,0' -trim 1.jpg)
```

Then execute it:

```
"${COMMAND[@]}"
```

I like `eval` but it's definitely not the solution this time.

And just a tip: If you can use a function, use a function. And quote your arguments properly.

Comment: I think the function is a much better idea. (You can include more complex shell syntax in the body of a function; an array is limited to the name of the command and arguments: no pipes, no lists, no redirections, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are not processed after expanding a variable. The only processing that occurs is word splitting and wildcard expansion. If you need to perform all the normal steps of command execution, you have to use `eval`:

```
eval "$variable"
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `eval` without knowing exactly what the OP is doing.

Comment: Although I'd prefer if he'd actually shown code, I'm pretty sure I understand what he's trying to do.

Comment: There are better ways of storing command line in a variable and executing it.

Comment: @anubhava Please post an answer showing the better ways.

Comment: No, I don't want to post an answer unless OP shows the code as I suggested in my comment on the question.

Comment: If `variable` is unverified input from an external source, using `eval` is dangerous. If `variable` is just set locally as a way of refactoring code, defining a shell function is better idea. `eval` is (or should be) a command of last resort, not a convenience.