# Run a bash command from a string

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have this function named `st` that let's me change the name of the terminal so that I understand what the terminal session is doing.

```
function st() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

So when I run `st yarn transportation start` the title of my terminal changes to `yarn transportation start`. So far so good.

I don't know much about bash.
But it pains me that I have to now run `yarn transportation start` to actually run that command. Is there any way that I can run anything after `st` after the title is changed?

I want to run a single command that changes the title of the terminal and runs the command that I gave in the title

Answer (score 0):

After setting title (setting `PS1`), you need to make sure that right `TITLE` is being used so that proper command can be run.

As pointed in [How to execute a bash command stored as a string with quotes and asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005192/how-to-execute-a-bash-command-stored-as-a-string-with-quotes-and-asterisk) there is eval function that runs the command from a string.

```
$ type st 
type st
st is a function
st () 
{ 
    if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
        ORIG=$PS1;
    fi;
    TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]";
    PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE};
    TITLE="$*"; # Take all the arguments
    eval $TITLE
}
```

You can even at a `-t` flag to provide a separate title and command like below

```
function st() {
  TITLE=$*
  COMMAND=$*
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  if [ "$1" == "-t" ]; then
    TITLE=$2;
    COMMAND=${@:3}
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$TITLE\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
  eval $COMMAND 
}
```